# Need help making score tally for Mr and Mrs game

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, vba, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to make a mr and mrs styled game where one user enters the answer and the other user tries to guess what the other person said. Everything works up until the part where the user's answers are compared to see who's is correct. I'm not sure what exactly is wrong. Any help is massively appreciated.

```
Module Module1

Sub Main()
    Dim Question(4) As String
    Dim P1Answer(4) As String
    Dim P2Answer(4) As String
    Dim P1Name As String = ""
    Dim P2Name As String = ""
    Dim Count As Integer = 0
    Dim UserScore As Integer = 0
    Const ArraySize As Integer = 5

    While Count <> 4
        Question(Count) = ""
        Count = Count + 1
    End While

    Count = 0

    Question(0) = " favourite colour?"
    Question(1) = " age?"
    Question(2) = " best friends name?"
    Question(3) = " favourite food?"
    Question(4) = " first pet's name?"

    Console.WriteLine("Enter the name of player 1")
    P1Name = Console.ReadLine
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the name of player 2")
    P2Name = Console.ReadLine

    Console.WriteLine(P1Name & ". Please get ready to enter your answers.")
    Console.WriteLine("Tell " & P2Name & " to go away while you answer the questions")
    Console.WriteLine("Press enter when you are ready to begin.")
    Console.ReadLine()

    While ArraySize <> Count
        Console.WriteLine("What is your" & Question(Count))
        P1Answer(Count) = Console.ReadLine
        Count = Count + 1
    End While

    Count = 0

    Console.Clear()

    Console.WriteLine("Tell " & P2Name & " to come back now.")
    Console.WriteLine(P2Name & ". Please get ready to enter your answers.")
    Console.WriteLine("Press enter when you are ready to begin.")
    Console.ReadLine()

    While ArraySize <> Count
        Console.WriteLine("What is " & P1Name & "'s" & Question(Count))
        P2Answer(Count) = Console.ReadLine
        Count = Count + 1
    End While

    Count = 0

    **While Count <> 5
        If P1Answer(Count) = P2Answer(Count) Then
            UserScore = UserScore + 1
        Else
            UserScore = UserScore
        End If
        Question(Count) = Question(Count + 1)
    End While**

    Console.WriteLine("Your total score is " & UserScore)

    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

End Module

Comment: set a breakpoint at the start of that loop, then watch the code execute; you can use the mouse to see what is in each answer array and being compared to determine the problem.  It does not appear to consider case ("Blue" <> "blue") and that `Else` is also pointless

Comment: The loop just seems to get stuck when I run the program after I've entered player 2's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a few issues with your code - The first one that's most commonly an issue is that capitalization may cause false wrong answers.

So, for example, Player 1 says her name is "Anne" and Player 2 answers "anne" - Your code doesn't take that into account.

The next issue is that you're not actually incrementing the `Count` variable.

Keeping with your style of coding, I'd suggest writing that loop this way:

```
Count = 0

While ArraySize <> Count
    If UCase(P1Answer(Count)) = UCase(P2Answer(Count)) Then
        UserScore = UserScore + 1
    End If
    Count = Count + 1
End While
```

Hope that makes sense!!